# What shall I look for in the output of `git pull` for errors and things worth my attention?

Tags: git

I write a script which runs `git pull` for each of many repositories.

So the output of running the script is very long.

I would like to find out if all the `git pull` calls succeed.

What words shall I search for in the output of running the script, in order to find any error or other things which need my attention?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would take a look at the exit code:

`git pull
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Everything went fine
else
    echo There was a problem
fi`

I think that's the syntax for if/else/fi on bash

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, if examining the output of `git pull`,  does `git pull` output something if something needs my attention or any error?

Comment: This is a convoluted way of writing `if git pull ; then echo Everything went fine ; else echo There was a problem ; fi`.  Same meaning, but the `$?` variable isn't actually necessary.